# Count anchor tag clicks when there are multiple tags with the same class

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a loop that I want to pull in the 5 most popular songs.  I want to simply capture the number of times the link to that song is clicked. I will return the button click count to an Action Result method in ASP.NET MVC, which will then be saved to the database.  When I run this I get undefined.  I also get this error for each record in a loop, and in this case, that is 5 times.  I am only taking 5 in my LINQ statement.

Here is my View:

```
@foreach (var song in popularsongs.OrderByDescending(song => song.Fightsong.PlayCount).Take(5))
{
    <tr>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Details", "Team", new {id = song.Teams.TeamId})'">
            <img src="@Url.Content(@song.Teams.LogoUrl)" height="35" width="35"/>
        </td>
        <td>@song.Fightsong.songname</td>
        <td>@song.Fightsong.duration</td>
        <td><a href="@Url.Content(@song.Fightsong.songurl)" class="playbtn"><i data-userid="@Url.Content(@song.Fightsong.FightSongId.ToString())" class="fa fa-play"></i></a></td>
        <td><span class="counter">1</span></td>
    </tr>
}
```

So the 2nd to last table column has a FontAwesome play button.  I have that wrapped inside an anchor tag.  When that anchor tag is clicked, count it and send it to my controller.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $(".playbtn").click(function (e) {
        var clickedUserId = $(this).data('userid');
        alert(clickedUserId);
        //$('.userdata-container').load('ajax/userpage_' + clickedUserId + '.html');
    });
});
```

This is returning undefined.

I realize that when I click the button, my play button icon will change to a pause so the song can be paused.  That will result in two clicks, but it should only be one.  So if there is a better way to capture this, please advise.

Comment: The `data-userid` isn't on the anchor tag with the `.playbtn` class (which is what `this` should refer to). It's on the `<i>` tag inside it. You need to find the child `<i>` tag and look at the `data-userid` *of that*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `data-userid` attribute on the `<i />` tag. Change this:

```
var clickedUserId = $(this).data('userid');
```

... to this:

```
var clickedUserId = $(this).find('i').data('userid');
```